# @RestController with StreamingResponseBody async.request-timeout not working

Tags: rest, spring-boot, asynchronous

I'm trying to get a StreamingResponseBody from a @RestController on a long running job.  It times out after 30 seconds, no matter what configuration I try.

This is in Spring Boot 2.0.3.
I've used the below test which shows the same behavior to try and get the configuration correct.

```
@RestController
public class TestController {

    @RequestMapping("/streamtest")
    public StreamingResponseBody handleRequest () {
        return new StreamingResponseBody() {
            @Override
            public void writeTo (OutputStream out) throws IOException {
                for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
                    out.write((Integer.toString(i) + " - ").getBytes());
                    out.flush();
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(500);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
       };
   }
}
```

I've tried the async.request-timeout setting defined here;
[Async timeout downloading a large file using StreamingResponseBody on Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42877498/async-timeout-downloading-a-large-file-using-streamingresponsebody-on-spring-boo#comment92771233_43496244)

I've tried overriding WebMvcConfig to set the timeout.  This method is never called.

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureAsyncSupport(AsyncSupportConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.setDefaultTimeout(3600000);
        WebMvcConfigurer.super.configureAsyncSupport(configurer);
    }
}
```

I've tried defining the ThreadPoolTaskExecutor:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAsync
@EnableScheduling
public class AsyncConfig implements AsyncConfigurer {

    @Override
    public Executor getAsyncExecutor() {
        return new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    }
}
```

It always times out after 30 seconds with a log;

```
12:14:28.028 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] DEBUG c.b.b.bof_static.config.BofStaticExceptionHandler - Async timeout for GET [/streamtest]
12:14:28.028 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
12:14:28.028 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Successfully completed request
12:14:28.030 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter - Chain processed normally
```

I'm unable to find any other solutions.  Can anyone point out what's missing?

Comment: I am having the same issue as yourself.  I've tried the below suggestions but none work for me.  Did you ever resolve this?

Comment: I never did solve this on my project, and moved on with a polling/status method that was good enough.

Answer (score 5):

Setting the following option in application.properties can solve this:

`spring.mvc.async.request-timeout=-1`

However, if you implement `WebMvcConfigurer` anywhere in your code, then the above option will be ignored, so you have to set it up as the following:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    // other config...
    @Override
    public void configureAsyncSupport(AsyncSupportConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.setDefaultTimeout(-1);
    }
}
```

You can also set it to a positive integer (milliseconds). The value of -1 will completely remove the timeout.

Comment: Worked perfect! I couldn't figure out why the property wasn't working!

Comment: Word of warning: be careful when setting `-1` as a timeout value, as this may lead to resource depletion in case of too many parallel long running requests. Usually one also configures an `AsyncThreadExecutor` with `config.setTaskExecutor(..)` in the above method. You should be aware that the # of threads that will handle async requests is defined by that executor.

Answer (score 1):

Open the application.properties add the following line

```
# in milliseconds 
spring.mvc.async.request-timeout=5000
```

If this is production code please do not set its value to -1. This in case of a large number of requests can lead to resource starvation. Cause clients will never timeout and will hold on to the resources they are using (thread).

Answer (score 0):

I already had a Spring Boot project set up on my machine with a configuration class like below ,

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class MyConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
  ...
  ...
}
```

I simply added `@EnableAsync` to it and below overridden method ,

```
    @Configuration
    @EnableWebMvc
    @EnableTransactionManagement
    @EnableAsync
    public class MyConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
      ...
      ...
    @Override
    public void configureAsyncSupport(AsyncSupportConfigurer configurer) {
      configurer.setDefaultTimeout(3600000);
    }
   }
```

I simply took your method to one of my controller classes and hit it from swagger. I don't see issue for few minutes. 
When I put your method without above changes to configuration , I do get ,

```
2018-10-24 11:35:55.085 ERROR 78852 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] c.h.a.a.aop.MyExceptionHandler       : Async timeout for GET [/test/common/streamtest]
```

so all seems to be working fine for me.

My only guess from your code is that you might have put `@EnableAsync` at wrong place.

Also, keep things minimal and don't experiment with `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor()` now and let your request be executed with default - `SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor`. Once you get your Async working with custom timeout, you can plug it in later.

I am running app in embedded tomcat.

Comment: I tried copying @EnableAsync to WebMvcConfigurer and the main application as well, just to see, but no help.  I think i'll need to try a fresh project with just this to see if there is some other config getting in the way.

Comment: I think, clue has to be the line that you written in your question - **I've tried overriding WebMvcConfig to set the timeout. This method is never called.**  I obviously, can't confirm as why that happens. Just wanted to prove with my simple answer that timeout can be customized.