# Downloading large(1gb) file from server caues request timeout

Tags: java, spring, file, webclient

So I am developing 2 services. One service handles file on filesystem and returns them via REST interface.
ServiceA:

```
        File zipFile = new File(folderDownload.getZipPath());
        try {
            final InputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(zipFile));

            return ResponseEntity
            .status(HttpStatus.OK)
            .eTag(folderDownload.getDownloadId())
            .contentLength(zipFile.length())
            .lastModified(Instant.ofEpochMilli(zipFile.lastModified()))
            .body(new InputStreamResource(inputStream));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new DownloadException(zipFile.getName(), e.getMessage(), 400);
        }
```

ServiceB is a public facing API that receives requests validates them and if the request is valid it retrieves files from serviceA and returns them to the client. For security reasons serviceA can only interact with serviceB so there is no other way but sending file through 2 services...

```
        WebClient client = WebClient.create(STORAGE_HOST);

        // Request service to get file data
        Flux<DataBuffer> fileDataStream = client.get().uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder.path("folders/zip/download").queryParam("requestId", requestId).build())
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM).retrieve()
                .bodyToFlux(DataBuffer.class);

        // Streams the stream from response instead of loading it all in memory
        DataBufferUtils.write(fileDataStream, outputStream).map(DataBufferUtils::release).then().block();
```

When downloading smaller files everything is OK. 
When downloading larger files I was getting outOfmemory exception on serviceB. I started using webClient instead of restTemplate and those problems went away. But now I am facing a new problem:

If file is large, the request timeouts before completing. So user receives incomplete file. What is the solution here?

The exception I see in console on serviceB:

```
2020-04-09 13:40:24.138  WARN 4106 --- [io-8081-exec-10] s.a.s.e.CustomGlobalExceptionHandler     : Async request timed out
2020-04-09 13:40:24.138  WARN 4106 --- [io-8081-exec-10] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.context.request.async.AsyncRequestTimeoutException]
```

Also I find it weird that when downloading directly from serviceA I get no loading indicator...

I have been on this problem for past week and I am slowly losing my mind. please help :(

kinds regards

Comment: A possible duplicate of - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42877498/async-timeout-downloading-a-large-file-using-streamingresponsebody-on-spring-boo. Refer answer by - Sir Metavirulent