# NGINX Ingress times out with large file downloads

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, kubernetes, nginx-ingress

We are running a Spring Boot app in a k8s pod that is hosted behind an NGINX ingress with a EC2 load balancer. Our app occasionally needs to send a very large file (10/20 GB). We have observed that this operation occasionally times out when querying through the ingress, but does not timeout when queried directly. To more easily reproduce this, we created a simple endpoint to request a file of arbitrary size (`/files/SIZE`). That is what you can see below.

When a request times out, the ingress controller does not seem to post any logs. From the HTTP client, when the request times out, here is what we are given:

```
{ [3744 bytes data]
100 16.4G    0 16.4G    0     0  22.7M      0 --:--:--  0:12:23 --:--:-- 23.9M* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS alert, close notify (256):
{ [2 bytes data]
100 16.5G    0 16.5G    0     0  22.7M      0 --:--:--  0:12:23 --:--:-- 23.6M
* Connection #0 to host INGRESS_URL left intact
* Closing connection 0
curl INGRESS_URL/files/21474836480 -v    31.47s user 26.92s system 7% cpu 12:23.81 total
```

Here is the configuration of our ingress:

```
kind: Ingress
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: USER
  namespace: NAMESPACE
  selfLink: /apis/extensions/v1beta1/namespaces/NAMESPACE/ingresses/USER
  uid: d84f3ab2-7f2c-42c1-a44f-c6a7d432f03e
  resourceVersion: '658287365'
  generation: 1
  creationTimestamp: '2021-06-29T13:21:45Z'
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: USER
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/name: APP
    helm.sh/chart: CHART
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx-l4-ext
    meta.helm.sh/release-name: USER
    meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: NAMESPACE
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/client-max-body-size: '0'
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: '0'
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-buffering: 'off'
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-max-temp-file-size: '0'
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout: '1800'
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-send-timeout: '1800'
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/websocket-services: core-service
    nginx.org/websocket-services: core-service
  managedFields:
    - manager: Go-http-client
      operation: Update
      apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
      time: '2021-06-29T13:21:45Z'
      fieldsType: FieldsV1
      fieldsV1:
        'f:metadata':
          'f:annotations':
            .: {}
            'f:kubernetes.io/ingress.class': {}
            'f:meta.helm.sh/release-name': {}
            'f:meta.helm.sh/release-namespace': {}
            'f:nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/client-max-body-size': {}
            'f:nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size': {}
            'f:nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-buffering': {}
            'f:nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-max-temp-file-size': {}
            'f:nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout': {}
            'f:nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-send-timeout': {}
            'f:nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/websocket-services': {}
            'f:nginx.org/websocket-services': {}
          'f:labels':
            .: {}
            'f:app.kubernetes.io/instance': {}
            'f:app.kubernetes.io/managed-by': {}
            'f:app.kubernetes.io/name': {}
            'f:helm.sh/chart': {}
        'f:spec':
          'f:rules': {}
    - manager: nginx-ingress-controller
      operation: Update
      apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
      time: '2021-06-29T13:21:59Z'
      fieldsType: FieldsV1
      fieldsV1:
        'f:status':
          'f:loadBalancer':
            'f:ingress': {}
spec:
  rules:
    - host: HOST_URL.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              serviceName: SERVICE_NAME
              servicePort: 9081
status:
  loadBalancer:
    ingress:
      - hostname: LOAD_BALANCER_URL
```

We are running `ingress-nginx`@`v0.46.0`

If anyone has any suggestions for why our large downloads are timing out, that would be great!

Testing Already Done:

1. Verified the params are actually appearing in the generated nginx.conf
2. Tried changing client-body-timeout - this had to effect.
3. Recreated the whole environment on my local minikube instance. The application works there. Is it possible this is an Amazon ELB issue?
4. Changing `spring.mvc.async.request-timeout` does not fix the issue.
5. The issue only occurs when making HTTPS calls. HTTP calls run totally fine

Comment: Have you already tried adjusting [`client-body-timeout` in the ConfigMap](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/configmap/#client-body-timeout)? Have you already confirmed those annotations are applying correctly in the generated nginx.conf? Basically what troubleshooting steps have you already taken and what are their outcomes? Don't put that in the comments, edit your post to show them

Comment: thanks for the suggestions. I have updated the post to reflect what you asked + one more piece of information.

Comment: Did you try changing the springboots timeout to a higher value?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion. Just tried this, and adding the request timeout did not change anything. Additionally, added some more information to the "Testing Done" section.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with one of my SpringBoot Apps and the issue was with the Springboot configuration in the application.properties file.

```
spring:
  mvc:
    async:
      request-timeout: 3600000
```

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43496244/2777988